# Adding and removing class on $viewContentLoaded for loading screen in Angular

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to add a loading overlay, as the site has lots of images in it, to my Angular build. To do this I want to add a class to the body to be able to have an opacity change on a child element.

What I have so far is a controller that adds and (should) remove the 'loaded' class:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('AppliedSiteApp').controller('LoadingCtrl', function ($scope) {

    // RESET LOADING STATE
    $scope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function(next, current) {

        $scope.isContentLoaded = '';

        console.log('route change');

    });

    // LOADING...
    $scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function() {
        $scope.isContentLoaded = 'loaded';
    });

});
```

This is fine on first page load of the site, but then the class just stays on the body on route change. Any ideas?

Comment: The event `viewContentLoaded` is raise whenever view changes in `ng-view` due to route change so, every view change would set this variable back to `lpaded`